# Odoo: Write function in Odoo 8

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I have one form with fields,

```
Name :
First Name:
Second Name:
Last Name:
```

I have written create function, when we enter first name, second name, last name, it will set the name

```
First Name: Test First
Second Name: Test Second
Last Name: Test Third
```

it will generate

```
Name : Test First Test Second Test Third
```

This is because of **create** function.

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    child = vals.get('child_first_name')
    child_middle = vals.get('child_middle_name') or ' '
    child_last = vals.get('child_last_name') or ' '
    if child:
        vals['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('application_form')
        vals['child_name'] = child + ' ' + child_middle + ' ' + child_last
    return super(application_form, self).create(vals)
```

When I edit any of these fields

```
First Name
Second Name
Last Name
```

It should set the name again.

Kindly suggest one **write** function with good way.

In the same Way:

Question 2 :

There is one boolean field.

For Reference:

I have written sequence Number to be generated in **create** method.
If I uncheck that boolean fields, other set of Sequence number to be generated.

Kindly suggest **write** function for both.

For Writing the above question

```
@api.multi
def write(self, vals):
    application = self.browse(self.id)
    if vals.has_key('child_first_name'):
        fname = vals.get('child_first_name') or ' '
    else :
        fname = application.child_first_name
    if vals.has_key('child_middle_name'):
        mname = vals.get('child_middle_name') or ' '
    else :
        mname = application.child_middle_name
    if vals.has_key('child_last_name'):
        lname = vals.get('child_last_name') or ' '
    else :
        lname = application.child_last_name
    full_name = fname + ' ' + mname + ' ' + lname
    vals.update({'child_name':full_name})
    return super(application_form, self).write(vals)
```

Comment: Thanks for editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can achieve this

```
@api.multi
def write(self, vals):
    # checks that new field value
    # is not equal to old one
    def _is_changed(name):
        return name in vals and self[name] != vals[name]

    # returns new field value if present
    # otherwise return old value if present
    # else return default value
    def _get_field(name, default=''):
        return vals.get(name, self[name]) or default

    # choose which sequence to use based on boolean seq_flag
    seq = 'some_seq' if _get_field('seq_flag', False) else 'application_form'

    # if one of name parts was changed
    if _is_changed('child_first_name') or \
       _is_changed('child_middle_name') or \
       _is_changed('child_last_name'):
        vals['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code(seq)
        name_parts = [
            _get_field('child_first'), 
            _get_field('child_middle_name'), 
            _get_field('child_last_name')
        ]
        # write only non-empty name parts
        vals['child_name'] = " ".join([_ for _ in name_parts if _])
    return super(application_form, self).write(vals)
```

Also you can use computed `child_last_name` field and [`@api.depends`](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html) to solve first part of your question

```
child_name = fields.Char(compute='_compute_name')

@api.one
@api.depends('child_first', 'child_middle_name', 'child_last_name')
def _compute_upper(self):
    name_parts = [
        self.child_first, 
        self.child_middle_name, 
        self.child_last_name
    ]
    self.child_name = " ".join([_ for _ in name_parts if _])
```

Comment: Thanks vsminkov.  I have a boolean fields **Example : For Reference**. When I check that boolean field Sequence Number will be as AM/001 and when I uncheck that boolean fields sequence number will be as ORD/001. Assume sequence number is created as ORD/001, I am going and edit that boolean field then It should be as AM/001. It should change only once.Because each time I edit other fields in that form sequnce will also be incremented